# Replacing numbers with SED

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace numbers from -20 to 30 using sed, but it adds "v" character. What's wrong?

For example: SINR=-18, output must be "c", but output is "vc".
I tryed to delete 1st character, but it returns 1 instead of j.

```
SINR=`curl -s http://10.0.0.1/status | awk '/3GPP.SINR=/ {print $0}' | awk -F "3GPP.SINR=" '{print $2}'` # returns number 
echo $SINR | sed "s/-20/a/;s/-19/b/;s/-18/c/;s/-17/d/;s/-16/e/;s/-15/f/;s/-14/g/;s/-13/h/;s/-12/i/;s/-11/j/;s/-10/k/;s/-9/l/;s/-8/m/;s/-7/n/;s/-6/o/;s/-5/p/;s/-4/q/;s/-3/r/;s/-2/s/;s/-1/t/;s/0/u/;s/1/v/;s/2/w/;s/3/x/;s/4/y/;s/5/z/;s/6/A/;s/7/B/;s/8/C/;s/9/D/;s/10/E/;s/11/F/;s/12/G/;s/13/H/;s/14/I/;s/15/J/;s/16/K/;s/17/L/;s/18/M/;s/19/N/;s/20/O/;s/21/P/;s/22/Q/;s/23/R/;s/24/S/;s/25/T/;s/26/U/;s/27/V/;s/28/W/;s/29/X/;s/30/Y/"
```

Comment: What is the output of `curl -s http://10.0.0.1/status` and what do you like to have as output of the `sed`command?

Comment: @Jotne SINR = number. Number from -20, to 30. I like to have "a" instead of -20, "b" instead of -19, etc.

Comment: When SINR=-18, the output of that sed command is `c` on my system. I suspect there is some other problem here, like perhaps SINR is getting an additional 1 prepended to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way would be more elegant and less error-prone:

```
echo $SINR | awk 'BEGIN { chars="abcdefg" } { print substr(chars, $1 + 21, 1) }'
```

Of course, `chars` should contain all the letters you need for the mapping. That is, all the way until `...VWXY` as in your example, I just wrote until `g` to keep it short and sweet.

With this solution your problem disappears.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need sed or awk if you have bash like you say you do. You can use arrays, which is maybe even less error-prone ;-)

```
map=({a..z} {A..Z})    # Create map of your characters
SINR=-18               # Set your SINR number to something
SINR=$(($SINR+20))     # Add an offset to get to right place
result=${map[$SINR]}   # Lookup your result
echo $result           # Print it
c
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mapping process, you're surely better off building a `switch` statement, a couple of `if`'s, or even using bash `associative arrays` (bash >= 4.0). For example, you could tackle your problem with the following snippet:

```
function mapper() {

    if [[ $1 -ge -20 && $1 -le 5 ]]; then
        printf \\$(printf '%03o' $(( $1 + 117 )) )
    elif [[ $1 -ge 6 && $1 -le 30 ]]; then
        printf \\$(printf '%03o' $(( $1 + 59 )) )
    else 
        echo ""; return 1
    fi
    return 0

}
```

And use like below:

```
$ mapper -20
a
$ mapper 5
z
$ mapper 6
A
$ mapper 30
Y
$ mapper $SINR
c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${SINR}" | sed 's/-20/a/;t;s/-19/b/;t;s/-18/c/;t;s/-17/d/;t;s/-16/e/;t;s/-15/f/;t;s/-14/g/;t;s/-13/h/;t;s/-12/i/;t;s/-11/j/;t;s/-10/k/;t;s/-9/l/;t;s/-8/m/;t;s/-7/n/;t;s/-6/o/;t;s/-5/p/;t;s/-4/q/;t;s/-3/r/;t;s/-2/s/;t;s/-1/t/;t;s/0/u/;t;s/1/v/;t;s/2/w/;t;s/3/x/;t;s/4/y/;t;s/5/z/;t;s/6/A/;t;s/7/B/;t;s/8/C/;t;s/9/D/;t;s/10/E/;t;s/11/F/;t;s/12/G/;t;s/13/H/;t;s/14/I/;t;s/15/J/;t;s/16/K/;t;s/17/L/;t;s/18/M/;t;s/19/N/;t;s/20/O/;t;s/21/P/;t;s/22/Q/;t;s/23/R/;t;s/24/S/;t;s/25/T/;t;s/26/U/;t;s/27/V/;t;s/28/W/;t;s/29/X/;t;s/30/Y/'
```

Use the t after s// to accelerate a bit.

vc is normaly not occuring if SINR is just a number like specified